# How to convert an Iterable to an RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, aggregate-functions, rdd

To be more specific, how can i convert a **scala.Iterable** to a **org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD** ?

I have an RDD of **(String, Iterable[(String, Integer)])**
and i want this to be converted into an **RDD** of **(String, RDD[String, Integer])**, so that i can apply a reduceByKey function to the internal **RDD**.

e.g
i have an RDD where key is 2-lettered prefix of a person's name and the value is List of pairs of Person name and hours that they spent in an event

my RDD is :

`("To", List(("Tom",50),("Tod","30"),("Tom",70),("Tod","25"),("Tod",15))
("Ja", List(("Jack",50),("James","30"),("Jane",70),("James","25"),("Jasper",15))`

i need the List to be converted to RDD so that i can use accumulate each person's total hours spent. Applying reduceByKey and make the result as 

`("To", RDD(("Tom",120),("Tod","70"))
("Ja", RDD(("Jack",120),("James","55"),("Jane",15))`

But i counldn't find any such transformation function. How can i do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I went through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284507/converting-a-scala-iterabletuple-to-rdd?rq=1 but sparkContext.parallelize is someHow trying to create multiple sparkContext and hence causing an exception. I want to keep single instance of sparkContext in my application.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: It is not possible. You cannot nest RDDs.

Comment: So, is there any other way to achive this solution from Iterables (without converting to RDD's)  ?

Comment: `flatMap` to convert your RDD to  `((prefix, name), hours)`, `reduceByKey` to get the total per user, `map` to get `(prefix , (name, total))`, `aggegrateByKey` (or just`groupBy`) to get `(prefix, List((name1, total), (name2, total),...)`. Easy.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thanks a lot for explaining. I appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a `flatMap` and `reduceByKey`. Something like this:

```
rdd.flatMap{case(key, list) => list.map(item => ((key,item._1), item._2))}
   .reduceByKey(_+_)
   .map{case((key,name),hours) => (key, List((name, hours)))}
   .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a tonn. Since i am new to scala, i can understand this solution but not very clearly. Some of the questions that i have includes : what does 'case' do here ? is the '++' operator in last actually adding elements to the list for same prefix ?  And the last one is : How can i sort the resulting ?

Comment: `case` is just normal pattern matching, `++` appends two lists, and you can use `sortBy` to sort the result :)

Comment: @Puneet Chuarasia edited my answer making it actually wrong(!!). The parentheses around "(name, hours)" _ARE_ in fact needed as it needs to be mapped to a list of tuples, not a list of type Any. I have changed the answer back to my originally correct answer.

Comment: Apologies for that and thanks for the description. :)

Comment: Generally, editing someone else's answer is really bad style (many of the highly skilled people here on SO would have raised hell if you changed one of their answers!) . If you feel something needs to be added or clarified, you should put that in a comment and let whoever wrote the answer decide whether the answer needs to be changed or not.