# Java - How to convert Iterable to JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-redis

I have a JavaPairRDD of (**String, Iterable[(String, String)]**) and I want this to be converted into an JavaPairRDD of (**String, RDD[String, String**]), so that i can use the reduceByKey function to the internal JavaPairRDD.

In this example, I have a JavaPairRDD where key is a specific model number and value is an Iterable of tupled item numbers and the price of that item.

Here is an example of the JavaPairRDD:

```
("Model1", Iterable(("1234", "55.00"), ("5678", "52.50"), ("91011", "551.65"))
("Model2", Iterable(("6546", "55.00"), ("6798", "1255.05"), ("98797", "500.65"))
```

After applying the reduceByKey function I would like the result to look like this:

```
("Model1", JavaPairRDD(("1234", "55.00"), ("5678", "52.50"), ("91011", "551.65"))
("Model2", JavaPairRDD(("6546", "55.00"), ("6798", "1255.05"), ("98797", "500.65"))
```

A very similar thread converted this RDD using the following Scala code:
[How to convert an Iterable to an RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208871/how-to-convert-an-iterable-to-an-rdd?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
("To", List(("Tom",50),("Tod","30"),("Tom",70),("Tod","25"),("Tod",15))
("Ja", List(("Jack",50),("James","30"),("Jane",70),("James","25"),("Jasper",15))
```

```
rdd.flatMap{case(key, list) => list.map(item => ((key,item._1), item._2))}
   .reduceByKey(_+_)
   .map{case((key,name),hours) => (key, List((name, hours)))}
   .reduceByKey(_++_)
```

Is there a similar way to do this in Java?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume the problem is - you don't know scala? Basically you need to write the same code in Java. The same RDD transformations.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans I realize that's my problem. I do not know scala enough to translate these transformations to Java or if it's even possible to do it the same way.